# How to stop showing menu in static home page wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ok, I'm creating a wordpress theme. I don't want my navigation menu to show in the home page "Only" if the site admin setup Front page displays > A static page (select below).

otherwise I want to show the menu in home page & other pages too. I've used this `<?php if(!is_front_page()):?>` function, but it is not working.

some one suggest me `<?php if(!is_home()):?>`, but it is not working either.

So how do I make it work?

Comment: It means you don't want navigation menu in your home page and want it in all other page ?

Comment: yaap, I don't want it only if site admin setup home page different than blog. like any other static page.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

1. `Dashborad` > `Settings` > `Reading`
2. Select  `A static page (select below)` option in `Front page displays` section.
3. Select the page you want to display from `Front Page` drop down box.
4. In `header.php` in the code for displaying menu, make the alteration as below.

   `if ( ! is_page( '{slug of the selected page in Front Page drop down box}' ) ) {
       //enter your code to display menu here    
   }`


   ?>

Comment: if I do it, my other pages ll stop to show the menu!

Comment: No, menu will not displayed in the specified page, but all other page will display it.